# Remove scroll acceleration while using touch pad

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want the wheel event to fire once. But because to the scroll acceleration this is fired every second. Is there any way to stop scroll acceleration or fire the wheel event only once?

I'm using HP laptop and this happens on all browsers, though the acceleration rate changes a bit. I haven't checked if the same happens with a physical mouse or not.

This is my code:

```
let animationDuration = 1000;
let lastTime = 0;
window.addEventListener("wheel", (e) => {
  let currentTime = new Date().getTime();
  if(currentTime - lastTime < animationDuration){
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  } else {
    console.log("in")
    lastTime = currentTime;
  }
},{ passive: false})
```

Comment: This a site for reference : http://kuon.space/

I can only swipe once per second. In this site. How can I implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to find the solution. I will try to explain my best with respect to the above code.

So what was happening is because of scroll acceleration I was able to `console.log("in")` every second but after observing the event `(e)` argument I saw that the `e.deltaY` is smaller than the last one every time so I just kept the track of "*prevDelta*" and if its smaller I wasn't calling the function.

**Use debounce to restore the prevDelta.**